# How can I fix error when trying to render data?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making an application to render the data in a table dynamically. But this error appears: "getUserData.map is not a function".
I didn't find any apparent errors, how can I solve this problem?

API: [link](https://interno.saibweb.com.br/api/v1/teste/clientes)
console: [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoKQK.png)

useRequestData:

```
 import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export const useRequestData = (initialState, url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(initialState)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url)

        .then((res) => {
            setData(res.data)
        })

        .catch(() => {
            alert('Erro')
        })
    }, [url])

    return data
}
```

Component:

```
  import { Container, TableHeader } from "./styles"

import plusImg from "../../assets/plus.png"
import minusImg from "../../assets/minus.png"
import editImg from "../../assets/edit.png"

import { useRequestData } from "../hooks/useRequestData"
import { baseUrl } from "../../services/api"

export const UsersTable = () => {
    const getUserData = useRequestData([], baseUrl)


    return (
        <Container>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <img src={plusImg} alt="" />
                        </th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Endereço</th>
                        <th>Cidade</th>
                        <th>UF</th>
                        <th>Telefone</th>
                        <th>E-mail</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {getUserData.map((user) => (
                        <tr key={user.TECL_ID}>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <img src={minusImg} alt="" />
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    <img src={editImg} alt="" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <td>{user.TECL_NOME}</td>
                            <td>{user.TECL_ENDERECO}</td>
                            <td>{user.TECL_CIDADE}</td>
                            <td>{user.TECL_UF}</td>
                            <td>{user.TECL_TELEFONE}</td>
                            <td>fulano@gmail.com</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Comment: What if you add ``{getUserData && getUserData.map((user)`` ? Also have you console.logged ``data`` in your hook before you return it ?

Comment: Above comment should work but you can also do this `getUserData?.map()` this makes it a falsy value at first then when the state of that variable changes it should re-render and display your data.

Comment: @OrçunGüler undefined check may not work here as map() doesn't exist on type never[].

Comment: @RitikBanger if this was typescript then maybe but plain js should allow that I've had similar results and was fixable with this.

Answer (score 0):

Few things, inside your custom hook, create a function to get the data outside of the `useEffect` and THEN, run it inside `useEffect`.

Now, you have to return your data state from your custom hook in order to use it, so... At the bottom of your custom hook (outside of `useEffect`) write this:

```
return { data };
```

Now in your `Component` you could do something like this:

```
const { data } = useRequestData([], baseUrl)
```

And that's pretty much it, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help, the error remained the same

Comment: Is the API returning an array?

Comment: Yes, returns an array of objects

Comment: Have you tried console log your data? Maybe res.data is not an array and you have to access another key like res.data.results or something... That error you are getting means you are trying to map over something that is not an array

Comment: Yes, see my console image link above.